# Netty - sending http requests over ssl

Tags: http, ssl, netty

I'm trying to get a client/server program exchanging http messages over ssl.  To start, I created client and server programs that successfully exchange http requests using DefaultHttpRequest.  The code that sends the request looks something like this:

```
    HttpRequest request = new DefaultHttpRequest(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.POST, "https://localhost:8443");

    ChannelBuffer buf = ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(line, "UTF-8");
    request.setContent(buf);

    request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.HOST, host);
    request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.CONNECTION, HttpHeaders.Values.CLOSE);
    request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/xml");
    request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_LENGTH, Integer.toString(buf.capacity()));

    ChannelFuture writeFuture = channel.write(request);
```

The client pipeline factory contains this:

```
pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpResponseDecoder());
pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpRequestEncoder());

// and then business logic.
...
```

The server pipeline factory contains this:

```
pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());

// and then business logic.
```

....

So far so good.  Client sends, server receives and decodes the request.  The messageReceived method on my handler is called with the correct data.

In order to enable the SSL, I've taken some code from the SecureChat example and added to both client and server pipeline factories:

For the server:

```
SSLEngine engine = SecureChatSslContextFactory.getServerContext().createSSLEngine();
engine.setUseClientMode(false);

pipeline.addLast("ssl", new SslHandler(engine));

// On top of the SSL handler, add the text line codec.
pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(
        8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
```

For the client:

```
SSLEngine engine = SecureChatSslContextFactory.getClientContext().createSSLEngine();
engine.setUseClientMode(true);

pipeline.addLast("ssl", new SslHandler(engine));

// On top of the SSL handler, add the text line codec.
pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(
        8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
```

Now when I send the request from the client, nothing seems to happen on the server.  When I start up the applications, the server seems to connect (channelConnected is called), but when I send the message none of the data gets to the server (messageReceived is never called).

Is there something obviously wrong with what I am doing?  Is this the way that https should work?  Or is there a different method for sending http requests over ssl?

Thanks,
Weezn

Answer (score 0):

You need to call SslHandler.handshake() on the client side. Check the example again its in there.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, it seems like I copied and pasted too much from the SecureChat example.

Removing the DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder seems to fix the issue.